# neo4j server version - traversal framework and number of http requests

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I know that `neo4j` database can be used both as embedded or server.

In `neo4j` documentation it says that `REST API` has an endpoint for `Cypher` queries, so if I issue `Cypher` query using `spring-data-neo4j` `@Query` annotated method, this query is sent to the database, executed on database side and then the result is sent back.

What about traversal API then? If I would submit traversal description using

```
findAllByTraversal(N startNode, org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.TraversalDescription traversalDescription)
```

does it send all traversal description to the server and executes it in server context (so there it is only one HTTP request)?

Answer (score 3):

Traversal API (package org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal) is only available via Java API. To expose your code using traversal API via REST, the recommended way is to wrap it into a [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Comment: And what about `org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal` and `RestTraversalDescription` class?

Comment: Commenting my own comment: does this rest traversal uses http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-traverse.html?

Comment: RestTraversalDescription is not part of Neo4j core, it's part of spring-data-neo4j.